# Unexpected error on Documen Libraries after enabling document conversion

Tags: 2010, web-part, error, document-converter

1. Configured the Document Conversions services in Central Admin.
2. Enabled document conversion on the "Document" content type from the site collection settings.

Now when I try to open ANY document library I get the following error message:

```
An unexpected error has occured.
Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have persmission, you can use this page 
to  temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For more 
information, contact your site administrator.
```

When I check the ULS it is logging a `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference is not set to an instance of an object`.

To troubleshoot:

- I created a fresh site collection and still had the same problem so it has nothing to do with my custom code.
- From the Web Part Maintenance Page I deleted the `XsltListViewWebPart` and the page loads fine, but with no control of the library.

Something must be configured wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this and will post it here for anyone else that runs into this SharePoint bug. Source: http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-developing-with-the-word-automation-services-in-sharepoint-server-2010

> Its works finally, by keep the 4 options of configuring the conversion
>   checked without click on apply button, since the ExcludedTransformers
>   then will not be added to the xmldoucment element inside the xmlscheme
>   for the content type. which not result of raising error when the
>   function: PrepareContentTypeFilter(SPList list, Hashtable[]
>   excludedTransformers) called to loop through unchecked options.
>
> it seems for me a bug from Microsoft when adding the
>   ExcludedTransformers to the hashtable
>   excludedTransformers[index].Add(key, type.Id.ToString());.